# How to make use of existing C structures in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a couple of header files that are already defined in C (C++ if we're being technical, but the header is C compatible) that I use to define a bunch of data types (structs). I would like to make use of these in a python script that I am going use to test the corresponding C++ application. This is mostly to avoid having to redefine them in python as some of the structs are unwieldy, but also it would be nice to have them defined in one place so if changes happen down the road it will be easier to adapt.

When I started looking into this I thought that this was *certainly* doable but none of the examples I have come across get me quite there. The closest I got was using cffi. I got a simple example working how I want it to:

Data types header:

```
// mylib.h
struct Point2D
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Point3D
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

Python code:

```
from cffi import FFI

with open("./mylib.h", "r") as fo:
    header_text = fo.read()


ffi = FFI()

ffi.cdef(header_text)


point = ffi.new("struct Point2D*")
```

But this fails if I have `#include`s or `#ifdef`s in the header file, per the cffi [documentation](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html?highlight=%23include#what-actually-happened):

> The declarations can contain types, functions, constants and global
> variables. What you pass to the cdef() must not contain more than
> that; in particular, #ifdef or #include directives are not supported.

Are there any tricks I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access C structs in Python. You will need to 'bind' C functions to Python functions. This only allows you to access C functions from Python - not a C struct.

Testing C++ is generally done using Google Test. If you require using Python to test C++ functionality then you will need to create bindings in Python to access the C++ functions (as C functions using `extern "C"`).

You can only bind to a C/C++ library. Google "Call C functions in Python" for more.